Do trumpets have similar agility to strings?
I mostly work with string instruments which are extremely agile and that often leads me to write virtuosic and extremely difficult passages for other instruments. My question is focused on the trumpet. Do trumpets have enough agility to rival that of strings and be able to play similar passages? Am I underestimating the agility of the average brass instrumentalist?

110bpm? Most instruments would comfortably manage at least 4 or 5 times that tempo, certainly tpts!!

I am downvoting this question because someone who claims to write “virtuosic and extremely difficult passages” should be aware of the fact that any intermediate trumpet player would easily be able to play this example passage at the tempo indicated.

Who are the likely actual performers? Or is this more a hypothetical question? In other words, are you just working in a DAW or are real performers in mind? In my orchestration book, Walter Piston's, many of the descriptions distinguish technique difficulties for average players versus virtuosi.

@JohnBelzaguy you misunderstood my question. The passage below wasn't supposed to be an example of something being virtuosic or extremely diffucult, those are two separate statements.

@JohnBelzaguy It's not my own claim, I've had players of a given instrument, mostly those of brass and lower woodwind instruments, say that my writing for those instruments can reach levels that are nearly unplayable, because as indicated in the question, I mostly work with strings and piano, which have very high agility and I don't have much real experience with wind and brass instruments

@Gregory I don’t believe I misinterpreted your question. Other comments reflect my thoughts on this. You cite the passage for trumpets as an example. There is no reason to include this passage as it is very basic and does not relate to your question, which otherwise is a good one. I will withdraw my minus vote. I suggest you edit and eliminate the example because it is not relevant to your question. As for your second comment, any instrument is capable of being played at a virtuosic level. You must learn the general capabilities of the instruments and the players you are writing for.

@JohnBelzaguy All right, done. I removed the excerpt.

The simple answer would probably be:

No, they just have different agility.

Each instrument has intrinsic features and limitations mainly caused by two aspects:

physical capabilities and limits based on its construction (not excluding limitations caused by the manufacturing of the instrument);
player capabilities and their physics limitations;

Consider your premise: you mostly worked with string instruments. Would you really write a similar passage on a double bass as you'd wrote it on a violin? I sincerely doubt it, as you're aware of the intrinsic differences between those instruments.
The other instrument families just expand those differences.
For instance, a pianist wouldn't generally be able to play more than (about) 10 notes at the same time and within the range of their hands, while an organist may be able to play more notes (since they can use their feet) and/or at quite different octaves, when using multiple keyboards. To put it simple, an organist may be able to play at least 6 notes at very distant octaves even when using only 3 keyboards (pedals included), something a pianist may never be able to.
Brass instruments are based on harmonics, meaning that they can quite easily "jump" octaves almost instantly, while this may not be always possible for a string instrument.
For instance, consider alternating between the middle C and a note 2 or 3 octaves above.
For a violinist, that's not immediate, as both notes require using left hand fingers at quite different positions, with strings that are not close to each other. There's a speed limit at which the player will not be able to alternate those two notes, or at least not reliably, also considering the jump between the non adjacent strings, which may cause unwanted notes in the middle of the passages.
For a brass player, that's relatively easy (depending on the instrument, the playing range and difficulty may change) because it's just a relatively small change in their embouchure: as long as they're experienced enough, alternating the same note between octaves is part of their basic technique.
Interestingly enough, a similar problem would be quite easy for a cello or a viola as long as the lower C is their first string.
Smaller intervals are tricky, though. The same relative passage may be almost identical in difficulty for a string player, no matter the reference note (let's not consider the matter of string length ratios), but it could be more difficult for a brass instrument based on its reference note.
As opposite to the above example, a fast passage between "closed" notes could be simpler for a string instrument (as long as the involved strings are adjacent and there's no significant position change), but probably more difficult for a brass one, depending on many aspects:

the position of the notes within the instrument range (higher notes in the instrument range can be played in many ways);
the tuning of the instrument (the same passage may be difficult on a B♭ trumpet but much easier on a C trumpet, and vice versa);
the physical limitations of the instrument (consider the case of trombone, which makes some position changes more challenging than others, since they're more "distant");

Note that similar considerations are valid on any instrument: the same "relative interval passage" may be more easy or quite challenging on the piano, depending on the reference note. Other instruments may have physical limitations that could make that passage either difficult or even impossible to play: consider the case of the pedal harp, which only has 7 strings per octave and any alteration to a "note" affects the strings on all octaves.
If you want to know if a specific part can be actually played by an instrument, and you don't have enough experience in writing for that instrument, you should then follow the two common paths:

ask to an experienced player of that instrument;
check the repertoire;

Note that, when asking to a player, you should consider a relative reference: many times composers ask to some musician they know (or the first they reach) without providing proper context or without considering their skills, experience and awareness. Ensure that you provide all context for your composition, including the possible level of the performers.
Repertoire considerations must be also be done with awareness: just because you found out that a piece X by composer Y "can" be played on an instrument, doesn't mean that you should consider writing something similar would be doable (would you consider Paganini's Capriccios as reference for writing violin parts?).
Orchestral parts that are in the known repertoire are probably the most reliable reference level: as long as you can find common similarities of a "playable part" up to early 1900 in an orchestral score, you're probably fine.
Still, always consider to ask an advised player about it, at least until you get enough experience and awareness about the instrument capabilities.
Finally, the part shown above can be easily played by any basically skilled trumpet player, probably including non professional ones.

Whilst I strongly agree with the opening statement that "instruments have different agility", in my experience, "…alternating between the middle C and a note 2 or 3 octaves above" is not "relatively easy on a brass instrument". In fact, alternating between middle C and the note one octave above is not easy.  On brass, large intervals are hard, especially at speed.

@BrianTHOMAS While I agree that large intervals are difficult and alternating between them isn't as easy as my answer could suggest, it still is normally more difficult on a string instrument, depending on the intervals and the notes involved. Coincidentally, some large intervals may be easier on one instrument than on the other, and vice versa. I'll rephrase my post with: "it may be relatively easier".

Your example is fine (though notated somewhat strangely rhythmically).   Strings routinely have to be MUCH more agile than that!

Yeah the software I'm using doesn't like to cooperate that's why the notes are weird. I knkw that strings are far more agile than in the excerpt, that was kind of just a middle ground to show what I meant.
